# Display audio level in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, microphone

I need to display current loudness of microphone input and dynamically update it. 
 As example - [microphone settings in Skype.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrDpA.png)
I've tried to find a libraries, but they all is for WPF or WinForms. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your question about getting the intensity (it's a number, in dB)?  Or about making a display?  These are two different parts to your problem and they deserve separate questions.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm gonna use a progress bar with range 0..100 to display the intensity.

Answer (score -1):

Seems orignal post is wrong direction and missunderstanding. See this API:[AudioDeviceController.VolumePercent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.devices.audiodevicecontroller.volumepercent#Windows_Media_Devices_AudioDeviceController_VolumePercent)

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about controlling and displaying the *gain*, but my understanding of the question is that it concerns the signal level not the gain.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but is not what I actually need.

Comment: @applexis Just provided an API which might help. But it is still not so clear about your whole scenario. Are you using MediaCapture to capturing photos, audio, and videos from a capture device? If so then the API I mentioned might work. Otherwise it is still wrong post.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yep. It is misunderstanding. Let me clarify OP's scenario again. If it is still not on the right direction for him, I will delete the answer. Thank you for point it out.